FFMPEG not compiling into a proper video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlPLkoh-mmY
The youtube video above summarizes my problem, as it would be rather tricky to convey the issue over a post. Any help is much appreciated on this, thank you!
Command used in video:
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -pattern_type glob -i '/Users/dimitrichrysafis/Desktop/distance_animation/*.png' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4

Folder (2.51gb) that I tried to convert into a video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UlxvVsjw2ofZeOULtFQfQ54UmHkMI77x/view?usp=sharing

Without looking, I'm guessing your filename numbers are not padded with leading zeroes, and your glob is not number-aware. So assuming hundreds of images, you're getting frames in "alphabetical" order. Basically any number whose first digit is 1 comes before any number whose first digit is 2, etc.

Thank you so much! I made a program to rename and compile them and it worked fully!

Please convert your comment into an answer.

@DimitriChrysafis I'm glad my guess helped. Please post an Answer to your own Question post, explaining what the issue was and how you fixed it. Then you can click the checkmark outline next to your own Answer post, to show that it's the accepted answer, which marks this Question as Resolved so that the SuperUser system doesn't keep showing it to people as if it still lacks a good answer.

I click it and it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days." I'll be sure to accept my answer as soon as it is available.

To solve the issue, I had to rename everything from 1.png to 1649.png to 0001.png t o 1649.png. Now it can go in numerical order properly. The code:
filenameStream << folder << "/" << setw(2) << setfill('0') << frameCounter++ << ".png";

